# How does Dependency Injection using ServiceLocator advantageous over creating dependent objects explicity in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ioc-container

It is possible to resolve the dependency by having a default constructor initializing the dependent object as below.

```
public class Foo:IFoo
{
public void disp()
{
//some code
}
}

public class MyClass
{
    IFoo ifoo;

    public MyClass():this(new Foo())
    {

    }

    public  MyClass(IFoo i)
    {
      this.ifoo = i;
    }

    void method1()
    {
     ifoo.disp();
    }
}
```

Similarly, all dependencies could be resolved by having 2 constructors as above, with which the unit testing framework could use the parameterized constructor straight away.

In this case, what is the advantage of implementing IunityContainer and service locator to create an instance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with providing a "fallback" or "default" implementation of `IFoo` that's baked-in to a default constructor and I'm not sure what it truly accomplishes if you are always instantiating objects via the container. However, it does break the loose coupling afforded by DI. I'm not sure I understand your question completely, and probably can't without knowing your particular use-case?

Comment: @Ic: There are two constructors. We could also instantiate object with the parameterized constructor by supplying the implementations. Forex: unit testing framework could use this. By that way it is loosely coupled.  Defualt constructor is to initalise the default class implementations to the  dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having two constructors is considered an anti-pattern. Take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97&month=6&year=2013).

Using the container as a service locator inside your classes is also considered an anti-pattern. Take a look at [this article](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/10/object-composability-another-reason-why.html) and [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

You should have a single constructor that takes in all dependencies, and then you should create the object in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).